# pthread for many class variables

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have a class which has many private variables. There are getter and setter methods for each. I have many threads which can access the setter methods and change the value of variables. Without having to write a mutex_lock and mutex_unlock in each of the setter methods, how do i make sure that only one thread is setting value for a given variable. (Please excuse if the question is too naive)

```
class MyClass {
private:
  int var0,var1...upto var99
public:
  int getVar0() { return var0 }
  void setVar0(int x) { var0 = x }
 .
 .
 .
}

MyClass mClass;

void *foo0() {
  processMyClassObj0(); //does some process and sets some of 'var' variables of mClass
}
void *foo1() {
  processMyClassObj1(); //does some process and sets some of 'var' variables of mClass
}
.
.
.

int main() {
  pthread_t p[100];
  pthread_create(&p[0],NULL,foo0,NULL);
  pthread_create(&p[1],NULL,foo1,NULL);
  pthread_create(&p[2],NULL,foo2,NULL);
  .
  .
  .
  pthread_create(&p[99],NULL,foo99,NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You do not tell us where and how often you instantiate the class you mention.

Comment: Why can't you use mutexes? Also can you use semaphores?

Comment: @alk : the a global object is created for the class which is accessed by the threads.

Comment: @alk , updated the question with sample code

Comment: "Without having to write a mutex_lock and mutex_unlock in each of the setter methods, how do i make sure that only one thread is setting value for a given variable..." By either a) making sure you only have one thread, or b) making sure no two threads contain code that attempts to write to the same variable, or c) using something other than a mutex (e.g. semaphore, reader/writer lock, etc.) to protect against races. What's wrong with a mutex, anyway?

Comment: @twalberg, i am under the impression that if we have to use mutex, we need as many mutex variables as the number of class variables (in this case it is 100) so that one mutex variable can be used per variable to  avoid changes made to it by another thread while it is in use. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: One mutex per variable would be the most natural way, and the best performing method, but you could use just one mutex to cover all of the variables if you wanted to. It would be bad for performance because of a lot of unnecessary contention on the mutex, but you could do something in between as well - maybe one mutex per dozen variables or something...

Answer (score 0):

you can give to your setter the "threadname" and compare with the thread you want modify to change your value.

```
pthread_setname
pthread_getname
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html

Answer (score 0):

If `p[n]` only uses `varn` (with `n` = {0..99}) you do not need any synchronisation mechanics.

---

**Update**:

Else if possible [declare the variables to be `_Atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) else protect access (typically by a mutex).

Comment: As i mentioned in the comments for 'processMyClassObj1()' or 'processMyClassObj2()', each method can modify some of 'var' variables. What variables are modified depends on the process, which means, there is no restriction on 'var' variables that can be changed(i.e any of var1..var100  can be changed by any of p[1..100] at different instances).